# Python Java Cross communication Servers

Tags: java, python, communication, cross-language

```
 +-------------------+                     +-------------------+
 |   Wowza           |                     |      Django       |
 |-------------------|                     |-------------------|       +-------------+
 |                   |                     |                   |       |             |
 |                   |                     |                   +------->   Database  |
 |     Java          |                     |      Python       |       |             |
 |                   |                     |                   |       +-------------+
 |                   |   v1,v2             |                   |
 |        A +-------------------------------------> X          |
 |                   |                     |                   |
 |                   |   u1,u2             |                   |
 |        B <-------------------------------------+ Y          |
 |                   |                     |                   |
 |                   |                     |                   |
 |                   |                     |                   |
 |                   |                     |                   |
 +-------------------+                     +-------------------+
```

Suppose A, B are functions in Wowza server, which is purely in Java. variables v1,v2 are private to function A.

Functions X,Y which are python functions implemented with Django/Twisted server. variables u1,u2 are private to Y. I would like your valuable opinion on solving two problems.

1. java function "A" executed, I want to run Python function "X" with variables v1,v2 from A.
2. When Python function "Y" executed, I want to run Java function B with variables u1,u2 from "Y"

A simple example is. When some one play a video via wowza, I want to inform django about that with user's client id. When the administrator generate a django signal, Wowza must know about it and accordingly..

**Is it possible with DjangoAMF, JSON-RPC or any other Message protocols? or is it possible with some middleware?**

Comment: What's the question, anyway? I think there is not enough info for correct answer. Is there any exchange protocol between wowza and django?

Comment: Its between Python & Java "Event" exchange

Comment: It is possible. I don't understand - what exaclty the question is? Java has a full set of different remoting libraries. Use spring remoting with YAML/JSON/or whatever transport. Write your own service or use Apache cxf - i don't see any problmes there. Question is too abstract

Answer (score 0):

Any RPC will be able to solve the above for you. I have not used DjangoAMF so can't comment on that. You can also expose some sort of REST API on both servers for this purpose.

Comment: I agree, using REST would be the easiest way to perform this, it is simple, effecient and does not involve trying to remotely access the other tech stach.